# Limit the number of background workers per user in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq, rails-activejob

I have a Rails application where each user has a specific number of background workers.

Since users pay more to increase the number of workers available, I want to be able to add these workers dynamically.

I would like to use `ActiveJob` in combination with `Sidekiq` and I thought about the following solution:

- when the user registers, I create a new queue in sidekiq with the `id` of the user.
- I add a number of workers, dedicated to that specific queue, depending on how much the user is paying.

I have problems in implementing this solution with Sidekiq and I could not find documentation on how to add queues and workers dynamically.

Comment: Yeah, this juggling of queues/workers is not very easy or scalable.

Answer (score 2):

If I were to do this, here's what I'd try first:

- Wrap all limited jobs in a counter.
- on start/dequeue job checks if this user has capacity to run it.
- If yes, job runs. If not, it reschedules itself.

Something along these lines:

```
class MyWorker
  def perform(user_id, *args)
    user = User.find(user_id)
    unless user.has_available_workers
      # re-enqueue with the same args. Possibly, with a delay.
      return 
    end

    user.checkout_worker
    # do work
  ensure
    user.release_worker
  end
end
```

Comment: I like your solution, but in this case all users would share the workers and not have dedicated ones. Which is not necessarly a bad idea: it could even scale much better, but it could be that there are no more workers available and the user has to wait (worst case, because he paid)

Comment: @coorasse: indeed. In this case, you might want to overprovision the workers, so that there's always some spare capacity. Which is a good idea anyway, if you offer paid service.

Comment: Agree. I still miss how I can add workers dynamically without restarting the application. This is not a killer feature, I can always restart the server, but it would be interesting to see if is possible with Sidekiq

Comment: @coorasse: add workers? You can just start a new sidekiq process. No need to restart/touch the active ones. Interesting devops task.